# Java Regex Multiline issue

Tags: java, regex

I have a String read from a file via apache commons FileUtils.readFileToString, which has the following format:

```
<!--LOGHEADER[START]/-->
<!--HELP[Manual modification of the header may cause parsing problem!]/-->
<!--LOGGINGVERSION[2.0.7.1006]/-->
<!--NAME[./log/defaultTrace_00.trc]/-->
<!--PATTERN[defaultTrace_00.trc]/-->
<!--FORMATTER[com.sap.tc.logging.ListFormatter]/-->
<!--ENCODING[UTF8]/-->
<!--FILESET[0, 20, 10485760]/-->
<!--PREVIOUSFILE[defaultTrace_00.19.trc]/-->
<!--NEXTFILE[defaultTrace_00.1.trc]/-->
<!--ENGINEVERSION[7.31.3301.368426.20141205114648]/-->
<!--LOGHEADER[END]/-->
#2.0#2015 03 04 11:04:19:687#+0100#Debug#...(few lines to follow)
```

I am trying to filter out everything between the LOGHEADER[START] and LOGHEADER[END] line. Therefore I created a java regex:

```
String fileContent = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
String logheader = "LOGHEADER\\[START\\].*LOGHEADER\\[END\\]";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(logheader, Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(fileContent);
System.out.println(m.matches());
```

(Dotall since it is a Multiline pattern and i want to cover linebreaks as well)
However this pattern does not match the String. If I try to remove the LOGHEADER\[END\] part of the regex I get a match, that contains the whole String. I don't get why it is not matching for the original RegEx.

Any help is appreciated - thanks a lot!

Comment: Regexes are probably not the best tool for the job here. Since you know the frontiers, just use a `BufferedReader` and use `.readLine()`.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Or if you want to rely on RegEx, try your RegEx with one of [this](https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#q=java+regex+test) tools

Comment: Did you read what `matches()` does? Are you sure you want to use this method? Maybe you are looking for `find()`. Also `.*` should probably be reluctant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing to remember about this Java `matches()` method is that your regular expression must match the entire line.

So, you have to use `find()` this way to capture all in-between `<!--LOGHEADER[START]/-->` and `n<!--LOGHEADER[END]/--`:

```
String logheader = "(?<=LOGHEADER\\[START\\]/-->).*(?=<!--LOGHEADER\\[END\\])";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(logheader, Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(fileContent);
        while(m.find()) {
         System.out.println(m.group());
       }
```

Or, to follow the logics you suggest (just using `matches`), we need to add `^.*` and `.*$`:

```
String logheader = "^.*LOGHEADER\\[START\\].*LOGHEADER\\[END\\].*$";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(logheader, Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(fileContent);
System.out.println(m.matches());
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to use `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes along with `find` method. The below regex will fetch all the lines which exists between `LOGHEADER[START]` and `LOGHEADER[END]`.

```
String s = "<!--LOGHEADER[START]/-->\n" + 
        "<!--HELP[Manual modification of the header may cause parsing problem!]/-->\n" + 
        "<!--LOGGINGVERSION[2.0.7.1006]/-->\n" + 
        "<!--NAME[./log/defaultTrace_00.trc]/-->\n" + 
        "<!--PATTERN[defaultTrace_00.trc]/-->\n" + 
        "<!--FORMATTER[com.sap.tc.logging.ListFormatter]/-->\n" + 
        "<!--ENCODING[UTF8]/-->\n" + 
        "<!--FILESET[0, 20, 10485760]/-->\n" + 
        "<!--PREVIOUSFILE[defaultTrace_00.19.trc]/-->\n" + 
        "<!--NEXTFILE[defaultTrace_00.1.trc]/-->\n" + 
        "<!--ENGINEVERSION[7.31.3301.368426.20141205114648]/-->\n" + 
        "<!--LOGHEADER[END]/-->\n" + 
        "#2.0#2015 03 04 11:04:19:687#+0100#Debug#...(few lines to follow)";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?s)\\bLOGHEADER\\[START\\][^\\n]*\\n(.*?)\\n[^\\n]*\\bLOGHEADER\\[END\\]").matcher(s);
while(m.find())
{

System.out.println(m.group(1));

}
```

**Output:**

```
<!--HELP[Manual modification of the header may cause parsing problem!]/-->
<!--LOGGINGVERSION[2.0.7.1006]/-->
<!--NAME[./log/defaultTrace_00.trc]/-->
<!--PATTERN[defaultTrace_00.trc]/-->
<!--FORMATTER[com.sap.tc.logging.ListFormatter]/-->
<!--ENCODING[UTF8]/-->
<!--FILESET[0, 20, 10485760]/-->
<!--PREVIOUSFILE[defaultTrace_00.19.trc]/-->
<!--NEXTFILE[defaultTrace_00.1.trc]/-->
<!--ENGINEVERSION[7.31.3301.368426.20141205114648]/-->
```

If you do want to match also the `LOGHEADER` lines, then a capturing group would be an unnecessary one.

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?s)[^\\n]*\\bLOGHEADER\\[START\\].*?\\bLOGHEADER\\[END\\][^\\n]*").matcher(s);
while(m.find())
{

System.out.println(m.group());

}
```